# Django formset access initial data in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a Django formset with a set of initial data which loads a foreignkey relation object into the initial form:

```
{{ cellcountformset.management_form }}
{% for form in cellcountformset %}
<div id="">
    {{ form.errors }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The relevant models look like this:

```
class CellType(models.Model):
    readable_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)

class CellCount(models.Model):
    cell_count_instance = models.ForeignKey(CellCountInstance)
    cell = models.ForeignKey(CellType)
    normal_count = models.IntegerField()
    abnormal_count = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I want to be able to display the machine_name of the cell referred to by the cell attribute of the CellCount model as the `#id` of the `div`. I use a ModelFormSet for the CellCount, which is passed a list of CellType objects as its initial data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form's initial data is stored in `form.initial`, so try:

```
{{ form.initial.cell.machine_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use the form fields to traverse models and get at the machine name, but I'll check. If you can, the syntax will be something like

```
<div id="{{ form.fields.cell.machine_name }}">
```

But I think that you are going to need to write a custom template filter for this. It can just take the form as an argument, and return the machine name associated with it (or blank if the form is unbound). Then you will be able to write

```
<div id="{{ form|machine_name }}">
```